# Were there any working computers using residue number systems?

Tags: history, architecture, design-choices, alu

Wikipedia says:

> A [residue numeral system (RNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) is a numeral system representing integers by their values modulo several pairwise coprime integers called the moduli.

Bit widths of each of those "several integers" will be much smaller than the width of the represented integer, allowing efficient addition/subtraction and multiplication, at the cost of complicated division and value comparison.

Here is a hypothetical example. Suppose that we want to represent 30-bit integers using residues. We pick several co-prime numbers - e.g. 1023, 1024, 1025, and represent value N as a triple `[N mod 1023, N mod 1024, N mod 1025]`. Note that the `mod` operation always results values of the same sign as the divisor.

In this particular case converting from N to residue triple and back is easy, as `N mod 1024` is just 10 lowest bits of N, `N mod 1023` is `(N[29:20] + N[19:10] + N[9:0]) mod 1023` which is very easy to calculate, and `N mod 1025` is, similarly, `(N[29:20] - N[19:10] + N[9:0]) mod 1025`, pretty much the same way as we mentally compute `mod 9` and `mod 11` of numbers expressed in decimal.

Then, adding or multiplying triples is done as adding or multiplying individual unsigned values mod 1023, 1024 or 1025 respectively. For addition, this requires shorter carry chains (10-deep) than would be used for 30-bit integers — or much smaller carry prediction trees, — and, for multiplication, just three 10x10 multipliers, one of them partial: we only need 10 lowest bits of the product to find out its `mod 1024`.

Converting a triple back to an integer is akin to solving a simple linear equation, reversing the way the triple was constructed.

Division would be much more complex, and less-than comparisons would be done by converting triples back to integers.

However, it could still be beneficial to use it for specialized computations, and there was a project of a Soviet military computer for the [anti-ballistic missile system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-35_anti-ballistic_missile_system) using a residue number system: [5Э53](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F5%25D0%25AD53), apparently unimplemented; a computer with a conventional number representation was used instead.

Were there any computers using a residue number system which made it to production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First RNS machine seemed to be tube-based EPOS (Elektronický Počítací Stroj) made around 1963 in Czechoslovakia.

The successor of that machine, EPOS-2, was transistorized and was built around 1973.

In USSR, there was Т340А machine, built also around 1962 and used for prototyping radar station machines. Later that machine turned into production К340А system, used for the same task.

Links:

EPOS-related (russian and czech):

- [EPOS 1 on the Czech wikipedia](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPOS_1)
- [EPOS 1 on the Russian wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPOS_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)).

General info regarding existing and only prototyped machines in USSR (russian only):

- http://www.computer-museum.ru/articles/uditskii/100/
- http://www.computer-museum.ru/document/sorucom-2017_30_Malashevich_s.pdf
- http://www.sorucom.org/articles/materialy-mezhdunarodnoy-konferentsii-sorucom-2017/1460/

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly, the Czech wikipedia article doesn't highlight the uniqueness of the architecture of EPOS 1. It says "modular structure". That's why when I'd found that article before asking the question, I dismissed the Russian version as wishful thinking.

Comment: In fairness, the T340A/K340A systems are not true stored program computers but rather plugboard-programmable calculators.